# Flutter Web: Converting dart:io File to dart:html File

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-io

Is there a way to convert dart:io File object to dart:html File? I tried `html.File file = dartFile as html.File` and it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The two file objects are completely unrelated.

I am not aware of any platform which has both the `dart:io` and the `dart:html` library available, so even being able to import both in the same program is surprising.

Answer (score 1):

No way. But you can handle it by having different code. See bellow:

```
  final _photos = <File>[];
  final _photosWeb = <html.File>[];

 if (kIsWeb == false) { //if its not web, handle dart.io file
  final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality:
        100,
  );

  File image = File(pickedFile!.path);
  if (image != null) {

    _photos.insert(_numberOfImage, image);
  }
} else { //if its web, handle html.file

  final temp = (await ImagePicker()
      .getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 80));
  final pickedFile = await temp!.readAsBytes();

  var image = html.File(temp.path.codeUnits, temp.path);
  if (image != null) {
    
    _photosWeb.insert(_numberOfImage, image);
  }
}
```